Debug in VS2017. Can't watch constant value that declared in static method
As an example, I have simple console app:
namespace Temp
{
    class Program
    {
        const double GlobalEps = 0.01;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const double LocalEps = 0.01;

            var result1 = 0.001 < GlobalEps;
            var result2 = 0.001 < LocalEps;
            var result3 = 0.011 < LocalEps;
        }
    }
}


So, I can't see value of "LocalEps" constant in debug, in Watch View.
Also, Visual Studio didn't show it by mouse hover on the name in code.
Visual Studio 2022 has the same behavior.
Is that a bug or something else?

@Sinatr While it may be true for C# as well, what you linked is specifically for unsupported expressions for Visual Basic. The question is about C#, and I don't see constants listed in the section for C#.

@Logarr, that's correct, you forced me to try on a new project and .. it works. So can't reproduce.

@Sinatr Good test. I have had issues lately in some projects where even my Locals panel is reporting variables being out of context, but it's usually due to a weird way the stack trace is getting handled around EF Core operations. I don't work with Watch enough to know if it can be affected the same way as Locals. Though with such a simple example I can't imagine they're getting a duplicated stack trace.

I tested it in VS2017 and VS2022 and the results are as follows:
VS2017:

VS2022:

VS2017 does have the problem you mentioned, but VS2022 can display the LocalEps value normally whether you hover the mouse or in the Watch window. After all, VS2017 is a product from many years ago, and it is normal to lack some functions. It is recommended that you use the latest version of VS2022.

Tested in VS2022 (with updates), value not displayed: screenshot

From my test results and some people's comments above, it can be seen that VS2022 should be able to display the value of LocalEps normally. It is recommended that you clear the Watch1 window and then re-add the LocalEps constant to the Watch window to see if the problem still exists.
